# Is there a registry setting I can change to make the default drag and drop to move not copy

Tags: windows-7, registry

I have a user that keeps whining that a file keeps copying and not moving.  After showing them multiple times what they need to do they still persist on complaining that "this needs to be fixed"

There is a program that does it but I dont' really want to download it
http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/34601-dragndrop-editor/

Inside they  said that the registry setting was

HKCR\AllFileSystemObject\DefaultDropEffect

and 
HKCR*\DefaultDropEffect - dword, values are 1,2 or 4

However I can't find that registry setting in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows often uses a concept where registry keys are only present if you want to differ from the default behavior.

This setting is once of those cases. The key is correct, you can just create it.

Keep in mind that although all other keys in AllFilesystemObjects are REG_SZ this one has to be a DWORD (also note that HKCR is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, I sometimes saw people mix it up with HKEY_CURRENT_USER). The value for "always copy" would be 1 for "always move" it would be 2, in this case decimal or hexadecimal does not make a difference as it is the same anyways.

The change will take effect without reboot, so you can immediately test it.

Answer (score 4):

## Simplified Instructions

1. Start Button -> Regedit <enter>

2. Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT-->AllFileSystemObject

3. Right Click inside the right panel and select NEW ->DWORD

4. Name it DefaultDropEffect

5. Set the Value to 2 (decimal or hexadecimal does not matter)

6. Save

7. Test immediately, no reboot required.

Values:

0 or delete = default action

1 = Always copy

2 = Always move

4 = Always create shortcut